# how to query those data ,which apper more than twice in table?

Tags: sqlite

I would like to query customer from order table and only customer order more than twice is qualifed.
Which clause or filter should I use to filter those customer order more than twice ?
Please help
I am using SQLite.

Best regards
tom

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT customer_id FROM orders GROUP BY customer_id HAVING count(*) > 2;
```

In the future, please provide more information such as Table definition or you'll probably get a few downvotes :)